# Disproportional processing time with arithmetic operations [C]

Tags: c, performance, gcc

Can somebody explain what is going on here with this small program?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a=0.577;
    float b=0.921; 
    float c; 
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<100000000;i+=1){
        c=0.7*a-0.2*b;
        //a=0.145*c+2.7*b;
    }

    printf ("%.3f\n",c);
}
```

Note, there is a line commented out.

I compiled it first without the line and then with the line. (Used `gcc -O2 ...`). And measured the processing time. I was very surprised to find out that execution time was `0.001s` versus `2.444s`. And this doesn't make much sense. Or rather, there must be some logic behind this.

Can you please explain what is going on and how to mitigate this problem?

I work on an program that process huge amount of data and it seems to me that I run into very same performance problem there.

I was considering switching from floats to integers but it seems that with integers it behaves the same.

EDIT: At the end the solution was trivial and logical. So I thank for all answers and explanations!

Comment: Did you look at the generated code?

Comment: What exactly are you iterating anyways? I don't see much room for something with such a dependency chain to be improved... (Which btw, seems to converge very quickly. I assume that high iteration count was just to make it testable.)

Comment: Try declaring `a` with `volatile`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first instance the calculated value was constant. The compiler would have calculated `c = 0.7 * 0.577 - 0.2 * 0.921` at **compile time**. Its even free to optimize out the loop as nothing changes within it (`a`, `b` & `c` are invariant).

In the second instance, `a` and `c` vary for each iteration so have to be computed `100000000` times.

Comment: Yes.  In the first line, c was just set to a constant by the compiler.

Comment: @Jim: No, the second line isn't constant. At each iteration of the loop, c depends on a, and then a depends on c. Nothing is constant.

Answer (score 3):

Good optimizers are very good.

Since the one-line calculation returns the same value on every iteration, there's no need to recalculate anything in the loop, so the optimizer doesn't.

When you change `a` too (with the two-line calculation), then it must run the loop.

Hence the difference in timing.

Answer (score 2):

Without the commented out line, the compiler can optimize out the whole loop. The value being set doesn't change with respect to the loop.

With the commented out line, the value of `a` changes at each start of the loop, so the loop can't be optimized out.

That is, your program and this one:

```
int main()
{
    float a=0.577;
    float b=0.921; 
    float c; 
    int i;

    c=0.7*a-0.2*b;
    for (i=0;i<100000000;i+=1){
        //a=0.145*c+2.7*b;
    }

    printf ("%.3f\n",c);
}
```

produce the same answer if and only if that line is commented.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I get from compiling your example with optimizations enabled:

```
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000f20    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f21    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f24    leaq    61(%rip), %rdi ## literal pool for: %.3f

0000000100000f2b    movsd   45(%rip), %xmm0
0000000100000f33    movb    $1, %al
0000000100000f35    callq   0x100000f3e ## symbol stub for: _printf
0000000100000f3a    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000f3c    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f3d    ret
```

Notice that the loop doesn't even run - the compiler has optimized it out entirely, since it can tell that the only assignment of `c` that matters is the last one.

In contrast, with the commented line reinserted, the loop must run, and the output code looks like:

```
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000ea0    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000ea1    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000ea4    movss   148(%rip), %xmm5
0000000100000eac    movl    $100000000, %eax
0000000100000eb1    movsd   143(%rip), %xmm1
0000000100000eb9    movsd   143(%rip), %xmm2
0000000100000ec1    movsd   143(%rip), %xmm3
0000000100000ec9    movsd   143(%rip), %xmm4
0000000100000ed1    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
0000000100000ee0    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
0000000100000ee3    cvtss2sd    %xmm5, %xmm0
0000000100000ee7    mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
0000000100000eeb    addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
0000000100000eef    cvtsd2ss    %xmm0, %xmm0
0000000100000ef3    cvtss2sd    %xmm0, %xmm0
0000000100000ef7    movaps  %xmm0, %xmm5
0000000100000efa    mulsd   %xmm3, %xmm5
0000000100000efe    addsd   %xmm4, %xmm5
0000000100000f02    decl    %eax
0000000100000f04    cvtsd2ss    %xmm5, %xmm5
0000000100000f08    jne 0x100000ee0
0000000100000f0a    leaq    87(%rip), %rdi ## literal pool for: %.3f

0000000100000f11    movb    $1, %al
0000000100000f13    callq   0x100000f1c ## symbol stub for: _printf
0000000100000f18    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000f1a    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f1b    ret
```

Quite different, as you can see.

Comment: It looks like machine + assembly code. How can I get this code on gcc?

Comment: I just disassembled using `otool` on my mac.  You can use `objdump` if you're on linux.  Alternately, the compiler itself will generate assembly (though it's often less readable) with the `-S` flag.

Comment: So you need to hand-assemble?  Do you just want the disassembler to check your work for you then?

Answer (score 2):

With the line `a=0.145*c+2.7*b;` commented out, the only expression inside your loop is loop-invariant. Your optimizer knows that, so it moves the computation outside the loop.  Then the optimizer notices there's nothing in the loop, so it gets rid of the loop.

When you put the line back, the expression is no longer loop-invariant.